# REST Polling in React + Flux

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm new to flux, this is a best practice question.

I have a server that i'm logging my app into, on a successful Login i'm returned a tokenId and an expiry time for that token which I put into a store.

tokenId is attached to subsequent API requests to ensure my sessions is valid. Before the expiry time is exceeded i'm required to send a request which generate a new tokenId.

Where is the best place to poll (setTimeout) token regeneration? I believe calling an Action or API Util from a Store breaks the Flux Flow diagram and this isn't logic that the View should be responsible for...

Comment: What's the point of having an expiry at all if you're just going to get a new one before it expires automatically? Why not refresh the token on authenticated requests? Also, storing the token in the store doesn't seem like a great idea. Do users need to log back in everytime they refresh the page?

Comment: The token is valid for up to 20 minutes after the user has left the app. If they visit the site again before token expiry they are automatically logged back in. If they visit the site and the token has expired they need to reenter their credentials.

Answer (score 2):

This is a specific version of the generic question "Where in the React/Flux architecture should async actions be triggered?" I've had many discussions about this, and there isn't a single "right" answer. Some options:

- **Trigger from the store**, starting the timeout when handling the `updateToken` action. This has the appeal of keeping all business logic in the store, but makes the store harder to test and reason about. One school of thought holds that keeping all store processes synchronous simplifies things.
- **Trigger from React**, either in your top-level `App` component or in a special higher-order component. You'd use `componentWillReceiveProps` to check for changes in the token value and start the timer. This has some appeal, as you're already listening for store changes and you can take advantage of various lifecycle events (e.g. clear the timer on `componentWillUnmount`). You're right that this isn't "view" logic, but the top-level React components often play more of a controller role than a view role.
- **Trigger in the "login" action**. This is more or less how Redux/thunk does it, leaving async processes to the actions themselves, but isn't as common in Flux implementations.
- **Have a separate API controller** that uses actions to communicate with the store. Someone still has to trigger `loginController.login()`, but further async processes are handled by that controller, and updates come to the store via actions. This controller might be wholly responsible for the details of the token and the renewal, so that the store wouldn't have to know about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, *Trigger from React* in a top level component feels like the best solution.